# Facebook Login App being Reviewed but only using default permissions

Tags: facebook

As far as I can tell my login app is only requesting the three basic permissions, which apparently don't require review. Yet the dashboard says my app is in review? Please can someone assist. 
Thanks!

Comment: You should post about this in the [Facebook Developer Community group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/). Facebook staff are active in that group and happy to resolve such issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue, seems I didn't need to click submit for approval, yet the button was there and available? Basically in my case I apparently could just click make it live. But once I had clicked ask for approval then it goes into review regardless of if just using standard permissions...